# 0 Padding on images

Tags: css, xhtml

OK so uh.. it seems like XHTML Transitional doesn't wanna take 0 padding...

Help? :|

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <title>Tadah</title>
    <style>
    body {
       width:1440px;
    }
    * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    img  {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:144px;
        height:90px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/63ba857eda5875ce057cffd1adf960d3?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" /><br />
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/63ba857eda5875ce057cffd1adf960d3?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens?  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: As bemace said, and also, I'd be surprised if it would stop padding working but that's not XHTML Transitional, as your doctype says, it is XHTML Strict (or at least it identifies itself as such). and running it through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) gives 12 errors. It may give a clue as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space between the images isn't coming from padding, it is coming from `line-height`. If you set `line-height: 0;` in the block that contains the images then they'll fit together without any space between them.

Using `<br/>` to stack images like that probably isn't the best approach anyway. You might have better luck with explicit positioning or sized `<div>` elements with background images. What will work best really depends on your specific situation though.